# Take in an argument when sending to channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to create a discord bot that takes in 2 arguments formats them with text then sends to a channel. Using this code it works but It doesn't send custom stuff. It can only be predefined how would I do this?

```
    if message.content == '!settrend':
    async def args(arg1, arg2):
        output = ''
        output += f"Changed trend of {arg1} to {arg2}"
        await message.channel.send(output)

    await args("test", "test") # I want this to be able to have custom arguments by the command.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of checking `message.content == '!settrend'`, you need to first split `message.content` by spaces, then check that the first token you get is `'!settrend'`.

So replace the first line with:

```
arguments = message.content.split()
if arguments[0] == '!settrend':
```

Then, at the end:

```
await args(arguments[1], arguments[2])
```

Please note that this solution requires the two arguments to not include spaces. If you want to be able to have spaced arguments specified by quotes (e.g.: `!settrend "first argument" "second argument"`), use `shlex.split` instead of the standard string split method:

```
import shlex
arguments = shlex.split(message.content)
```